# How to get program to not throw "Error: Can't load Floyd's algorithm library"

Tags: python, windows, linux, isometric

another question for all of you-

So i am trying to get a program called Pysomap to work (its basically ISOMAP but for python[http://web.vscht.cz/spiwokv/pysomap/]), i follow the directions best as i can, building it on Ubuntu, Windows, and Fedora (prebuilt libraries), but cant seem to get it to work. On windows (which is the preferred implementation platform), every time i go to python and import pysomap, it gives me the above error. Anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks

-J

Comment: There are far too many open ended aspects here. Is that the best traceback message you can provide? Did you notice any build errors when you compiled the library?

Comment: I think we need some traceback/errors/code to get a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: So there are no traceback errors... i was going through the pysomap code, and it does this:

# Try to import floyd
try:
  from floyd import *
except:
  print "Error: Can't load Floyd's algorithm library"
  sys.exit(2)


Which means that it cant find Floyds? The thing which baffles me, is that it is in the directory...

Comment: Consider [scikits-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#isomap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pysomap directory, create a setup.py file with the following content:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="pysomap",
      version="2007.07",
      url ="http://web.vscht.cz/spiwokv/pysomap/",
      description="A library for isometric feature mapping.",
      license='Unknown',
      author="Vojtech Spiwok",
      py_modules=["floyd", "pysomap"],
      ext_modules=[Extension('_floyd', ["floyd_wrap.c", "floyd.c"])]
      )
```

Build the `_floyd` extension (assuming you have a Python distutils compatible C compiler installed):

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Run demo.py:

```
python demo.py

Calculating distance matrix ............    2.24 s
Using epsilon-isomap, epsilon = 0.500000, calculating 2-dimensional embedding
Calculating graph matrix ...............    1.21 s
Calculating the shortest path matrix ...    2.22 s
Multidimensionally scalling ............    7.11 s
--------------------------------------------------
Total procedure ........................   12.79 s
```

Comment: This is pretty genius. I couldn't even manage to overcome an architecture issue building manually on OSX, but your distutils setup.py in combination with ARCHFLAGS actually worked. Not that I personally care to use this library, but I was trying to figure out a solution for the OP myself.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the code because Isomap is a cool algorithm. The code doesn't look like it was written  by someone familiar with Python, and the whole floyd extension module compilation is sort of shoddy - it actually didn't build for me, and I'm pretty sure that's your problem (they catch the import exception for the module and print out the error that you give).

I changed some hard-coded stuff in `build_floyd.sh` to different hard-coded values for my system. (A proper build system would make this unnecessary). Here's what worked in my Ubuntu system. I tested and it ran ok.

```
#!/bin/sh
# run this script to generate library for Floyd's
# algorithm library

echo "generating input files using SWIG ..."
swig -python floyd.i

echo "compiling ..."
# change compiler if you use other than gcc
gcc -c floyd.c floyd_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -fPIC

echo "linking ..."
ld -shared floyd.o floyd_wrap.o -o _floyd.so 

#echo "for SELinux you must run chcon ..."
#chcon -t textrel_shlib_t _floyd.so
```

You may also have to change the first line in `demo.py` to `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Answer (score 0):

This source code is over 5 years old and the build script for floyd looks to assume hard-coded python2.4.

It seems pretty clear that your `floyd` module did not build. You will most likely have to go back to the build step and ensure that you are properly generating a `_floyd.so`.

If you built it correctly, then this should not fail for you:
    `python -c "import _floyd"`